# Improving my failing regex

Tags: c#, regex, string

My regex was working - until the form of the string it was capturing slightly changed. It used to always be of the form :

```
Word1 - Word2 - 01.2.3456.7890 - xx-xx - Word 3 [Word-inbracket]
```

Where I was interested in capturing the `xx-xx`.

For capturing this data, the following regex worked :

```
(.+\s*-\s*.+\s*-\s*.+)\s*-\s*(\w{1,3}\s*-\s*\w{1,3})\s*-\s*.+
```

Selecting groups[2] from it.

Now, however, the string has changed form so that sometimes there is another dash, and another set of letters between 1 and 4 characters after the `xx-xx`. (Remember, this only happens sometimes).

So, now I also need to capture the info where it is of the form :

```
Word1 - Word2 - 01.2.3456.7890 - xx-xx-XxxX - Word 3 [Word-inbracket]
Word1 - Word2 - 01.2.3456.7890 - xXX-XxX-xxxx - Word 3 [Word-inbracket]
```

Etc.

How can I edit my regex to capture this string in addition to the ones that were previously caught? What is the cleanest way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little hacky but that will do the trick:

```
(.+\s*-\s*.+\s*-\s*.+)\s*-\s*((\w{1,3}\s*-\s*\w{1,3})|(\w{1,4}\s*-\s*\w{1,4}))\s*-\s*.+
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should do it:

```
(.+?\s*-\s*.+?\s*-\s*.+?)\s*-\s*(\w{1,3}\s*-\s*\w{1,3})\s*(?:-(\w{1,3}))?\s*-\s*.+
```

The changes I've made are:

- Made the any characters matches at the beginning non-greedy by adding '?' after them — this stops them gobbling up too much when the extra bit is present.
- Added the '(?:-(\w{1,3}))?' which matches the optional extra bit if it is present, but without capturing the '-' prefix (the '?:' makes the outer group non-capturing).

This will give you an extra capturing group that includes the optional bit.

You can see it in action [here](http://regexr.com?31guu) (edited).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the input lines, a more simplified approach could be taken altogether.

The following regex matches both cases and should also work for any other modifications to the part the was modified.

```
([^-]*-){3}\s*([^\s]+).*
```

This should capture the first group of with "Word1 - Word2 - 01.2.3456.7890 -", and then the second group of "xx-xx-XxxX".

Also note, I'm going off of the assumption that the second desired group does not contain spaces as the example strings do not have them.

Explained:

```
([^-]*-){3}    # captures the "word1 - word2 - word3.234.234 -" block
\s*
([^\s]+)       # captures the "xx-xx-xxx" block up to the first whitespace char.
.*             # matches the rest of the line
```

Answer (score 0):

this is more clear .+\s-\s(.+)\s-\s.+$